# Render LightWave (.lwo) file in wpf application

Tags: wpf

I have been tasked with rendering a .lwo file in a WPF application. I have done a bit of digging and found that a site called www.shaxam.com used to provide an online converter, but that doesn't seem to exist anymore.

How else can I go about rendering a Lightwave 3d file in a wpf application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Helix 3D Toolkit](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/) might help. It is a beta, but seems to be an active project.